# A quadratic polynomial f satisfies $f(x) \geq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A quadratic polynomial $f$ satisfies $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$, $f(1)=0$, and $f(3)=3$. What is $f(5)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have $f(1)=0$ so $1$ is a root of $f$ and since $f\ge0$ so $1$ is the only root hence
$$f(x)=a(x-1)^2$$
the coefficient $a$ is determined by $f(3)=3$.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.